# CGPostError on setting UIProgressView.trackTintColor

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have a symbolic breakpoint on `CGPostError` symbol.
The code works fine is iOS 10 or higher, but sometimes crashes on iOS 9 (only).

Breakpoint (and crashes) happens in such function:

```
private func colourProgressBar(withViewState viewState: ViewState) {
        if viewState == .paused {
            progressView.progressTintColor = .green
            progressView.trackTintColor = .red
        } else {
            progressView.progressTintColor = .yellow // here it crashes/stops on breakpoint
            progressView.trackTintColor = .violet
        }
    }
```

Basically, it's happening when the progressView is hidden (and I'm not sure if it happens when it's not hidden). Still, it shouldn't matter whether that's hidden or not. The progress view exists, so setting that property shouldn't cause any errors..?